# Leaflet - global variable in onEachFeature returns value of next feature

Tags: leaflet, geojson

Thanks to [TomazicM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/104146/tomazicm) I got my GeoJSON import up and running. Here's the whole code, I highlight the problematic bits thereafter

```
    var map = L.map('map', {
        crs: L.CRS.Simple,
        minZoom: -1
    });


//TODO - set the image width and height to w and h
    var w = 1700;
    var h = 2200;

    //the stuff to be able to work with xy instead of latlon
    var yx = L.latLng;
    var xy = function(x, y) {
        if (L.Util.isArray(x)) {    // When doing xy([x, y]);
            return yx(x[1], x[0]);
        }
        return yx(y, x);  // When doing xy(x, y);
    };

    var bounds = [xy(0, 0), xy(w, h)];
        map.fitBounds(bounds).setMaxBounds(bounds); //this makes the map fit the bounds we just defined

//TODO - insert image name here
    var image = L.imageOverlay('img/kisandra.png', bounds).addTo(map);


    //create map icon class by extending L.Icon
    var TaladasIcon = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {
        iconSize:     [50, 50],
        iconAnchor:   [25, 25],
        popupAnchor:  [0, -25]
        }
    });

    //define custom icons
    var metropolisIcon = new TaladasIcon({iconUrl: '/img/metropolis.png'}),
        cityIcon = new TaladasIcon({iconUrl: 'img/city.png'}),
        townIcon = new TaladasIcon({iconUrl: 'img/town.png'}),
        villageIcon = new TaladasIcon({iconUrl: 'img/village.png'}),
        innIcon = new TaladasIcon({iconUrl: 'img/tankard.png'});


    var featureIcon     = villageIcon;


function forEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        var popupContent = "<p> <b>" + feature.properties.name + 
            "</b></br>"+ feature.properties.description +
            "</br>"+ feature.properties.icon +"</p>";
        featureIcon     = window[feature.properties.icon];
        layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    }


var jsonMetropolis = L.geoJSON([], {
  onEachFeature: forEachFeature,
  pointToLayer: function (feature, yx) {
    return L.marker(yx, {
      icon: featureIcon
    });
  }
});

$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "data/metropolises.geojson",
  success: function(data) {
    $(data.features).each(function(key, data) {
      jsonMetropolis.addData(data);
    });
    jsonMetropolis.addTo(map);
  }
});
```

As you can see after I defined my custom icons, I define a variable called featureIcon and assign it a random icon, just so it's not null `var featureIcon     = villageIcon;`
Then in the `forEachFeature` function I set the variable equal to a field in the geoJSON         `featureIcon     = window[feature.properties.icon];` and later the marker is told to use said icon `L.marker(yx, {icon: featureIcon})`

Funny thing is, while the popups that are set in forEachFeature too, are displaying correctly the property field's contents, the icon is offset by one feature. The first feature displays the pre-set icon, the second feature displays the icon specified in feature 1, the third the icon from feature 2, etc.

What am I doing wrong this time? Wrong use of the global variable thing `window[]` ? Or `something else?

Comment: Put all marker-initialization-related code in `pointToLayer`. You're messing up the scope of the variables horribly in there, hoping that there won't be race conditions at all (i.e. you're hoping that each pass of `onEachFeature` happens just *before* each pass of `pointToLayer` -which is wrong because `onEachFeature` receives the already-instantiated marker so it happens *after*- and there's no guarantee of that synchronicity at all).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that, working now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from [IvanSanchez](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/53755/ivansanchez) resolved this.

Moving `featureIcon     = window[feature.properties.icon];` from the `forEachLayer` function to the `pointToLayer` function did the trick.